# Crashed when storing Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-uranium

I was depositing Pokémon in the PC at Kevlar Town's Pokémon Center. When I selected `Store` in the option menu (for what to do with the Pokémon), the game opened a popup with this error. It dumped it into the Save folder. The game froze, but music is still playing. I haven't saved in a while, so my question is: **Can I safely close the game without losing my data?**

> Exception: RuntimeError Message: Script error within event 7, map 68
>   (Kevlar Town): Exception: NoMethodError Message: Section141:291:in
>   `pbStore'undefined method`mail' for nil:NilClass
>   ***Full script: pbPokeCenterPC
>
> Interpreter:243:in `pbExecuteScript' PScreen_Storage:734:in`
>   pbStartScreen' PScreen_Storage:668:in `loop' PScreen_Storage:753:in`
>   pbStartScreen' PScreen_Storage:3105:in `access'
>   PScreen_Storage:3102:in`pbFadeOutIn' PScreen_Storage:3102:in `access'
>   PScreen_Storage:3078:in`loop' PScreen_Storage:3110:in `access'
>   PScreen_Storage:3026:in`callCommand'
>
> Interpreter:276:in `pbExecuteScript' Interpreter:1600:in`command_355'
>   Interpreter:494:in `execute_command' Interpreter:193:in`update'
>   Interpreter:106:in `loop' Interpreter:198:in`update'
>   * Scene_Map:103:in `update'
>   * Scene_Map:101:in`loop'
>   * Scene_Map:139:in `update' Debug Passability:275:in`main'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know for sure. But you can make an attempt at backing up your save.

- Go to (C:/Users/Your Name/Saved Games/Pokemon Uranium)
- Find Uranium_[your save file number].rxdata
- copy it somewhere else

In the event the save is corrupted, try pasting that back in, however, I've had experience with Uranium corruptions before, and they're pretty much unrecoverable